# Cant get digest auth to work with node.js

Tags: http, node.js, authorization

I'm trying to get a simple (!) digest authentication working with node js using an an API from gathercontent.com.

Everything seems to be working except I still get a "Wrong credentials" response that looks like this:

```
{ success: false, error: 'Wrong Credentials!' }
```

The code looks like this:

```
var https = require('https'),
    qs = require('querystring');
apikey = "[my api key goes in here]",
    pwd = "[my password goes in here]",
    crypto = require('crypto');


module.exports.apiCall = function () {

    var options = {
        host:'abcdefg.gathercontent.com',
        port:443,
        path:'/api/0.1/get_pages_by_project/get_me',
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            "Accept":"application/json",
            "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {

        res.on('data', function (d) {
            var creds = JSON.parse(d);


            var parsedDigest = parseDigest(res.headers['www-authenticate']);
            console.log(parsedDigest);
            var authopts = {
                host:'furthercreative.gathercontent.com',
                port:443,
                path:'/api/0.1/get_pages_by_project/get_me',
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    "Accept":"application/json",
                    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization" : getAuthHeader(parsedDigest, apikey, parsedDigest['Digest realm'], pwd)
                }
            };

            console.log(authopts);
            console.log('\n\n\n');
            var req2 = https.request(authopts, function (res2) {
                console.log("statusCode: ", res2.statusCode);
                console.log("headers: ", res2.headers);


                res2.on('data', function (d2) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(d2);

                });
            });

            req2.end();



        });

    });


    req.write('id=1234');

    req.end();

    req.on('error', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });

};

function parseDigest(s){

    var parts = s.split(',');
    var obj = {};
    var nvp = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){

        nvp = parts[i].split('=');
        obj[nvp[0]] = nvp[1].replace(/"/gi, '');
    }



    return obj;
}

function getAuthHeader(digest, apikey, realm, pwd){
    var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
    var s = '';

    var nc = '00000001';
    var cn = '0a4f113b';

    var HA1in = apikey+':'+realm+':'+pwd;
    md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
    md5.update(HA1in);
    var HA1out = md5.digest('hex');

    var HA2in = 'POST:/api/0.1/get_pages_by_project/get_me';
    md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
    md5.update(HA2in);
    var HA2out = md5.digest('hex');

    md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
    var respIn = HA1out + ':' + digest.nonce + ':'+nc+':'+cn+':'+digest.qop+':'+ HA2out;
    md5.update(respIn);
    var resp = md5.digest('hex');


    s = [   'Digest username="',apikey,'", ',
        'realm="',digest['Digest realm'],'", ',
        'nonce="',digest.nonce,'", ',
        'uri="/api/0.1/get_pages_by_project/get_me", ',
        'cnonce="',cn,'", ',
        'nc="',nc,'", ',
        'qop="',digest.qop,'", ',
        'response="',resp,'", ',
        'opaque="',digest.opaque,'"'].join('')

    return s;
}
```

I'd try and Curl to it but I'm not sure how!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should make the `cnonce` a non-constant random value, to prevent precomputed dictionary attacks and others, see [section 4.9ff in the spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#section-4.9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a couple of issues potentially related to your problem. It's hard to tell which ones are the actual culprits, not knowing anything about gathercontent's implementation. If you pasted an example of their 'WWW-Authenticate' header, it would be much easier to provide specific help.

So I'm speculating what the actual cause is, but here are some actual problems that you should address anyway, to conform to the spec (i.e. protect it from breaking in the future because the server starts doing things slightly differently):

- in the `Authorization` headers you are creating, **remove the double quotes** around `nc`, and maybe also `qop`
- I don't know what `qop` value gathercontent is using. If it's **`auth-int`**, then you'd also have to append the hashed HTTP body to `HA2`, see [#3.2.2.3 of the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.2.3) - furthermore, they might be specifying **a comma-separated list of qop values** for you to choose from - or the server **might not send a value for `qop` at all**, i.e. they use the most basic from of HTTP digest auth, in which your implementation would be violating the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.2), as then you aren't allowed to e.g. send a `cnonce`, `nc` etc.
- you try to get the realm via `parsedDigest['Digest realm']`, i.e. **you are assuming that the `realm` is the first attribute after the initial `Digest`** keyword. That might or might not be the case, but you should not rely upon it (modify your `parseDigest` function to strip of the string `"Digest "` before splitting the rest)
- the way you use `parsedDigest`, you make the assumption that **Digest** is always capitalized that way, and that **`realm`, `nonce`, etc.** are always in lowercase. According to the spec, these are all **case-insensitive**

A couple of unrelated issues:

- Does the server really force you to use `Digest authentication`? This is HTTPS, so you might as well do `Basic authentication`, it's way easier, and with HTTPS, just as safe. (Answering myself here, after checking out gathercontent: Basic auth is apparently [not possible](http://help.gathercontent.com/customer/portal/articles/250475-getting-started-with-gathercontent-api))
- As mentioned in my comment to your question, `cnonce` should be random for every request, especially, you shouldn't copy and paste it from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation), which makes you more vulnerable (but not an issue here, as all data goes over SSL anyway in your case)

Regarding how to curl it - try this:

```
curl --data 'id=1234' --digest --user "apikey:pwd" https://abcdefg.gathercontent.com:443/api/0.1/get_pages_by_project/get_me
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, for the detailed answer, I'll work through your suggestions. 
The 'qop' = 'auth' from GatherContent. I tried to follow the rfc2617 standards. 
My code is a bit hacked together (hence the "Digest Realm") as I was trying to get authentication before refactoring ... might have to rethink this! :)

Comment: Have to give the bounty to Eugene, because of the extent of his answer and helping make clear that I had digets working, as that was the intent of my question. The solution though was to change the password character in the request :(

Answer (score 3):

It's Peter from GatherContent.

The first, pretty obvious thing would be to use just `get_me` instead of `get_pages_by_project/get_me`. You are mixing two different things in the latter. `get_me` doesn't require any parameters sent via POST, so you can drop them.

Also, please make sure that your password is always lowercase `x`.

Does it change anything?

**Edit:**
For anyone interested, here's our API docs:
http://gathercontent.helpjuice.com/questions/26611-How-do-I-use-the-API

Comment: The confusion was that the password needed to be a lowercase single x character rather than my existing password in lowercase, which I had thought was odd. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 1):

The `express-auth` module supports multiple authentication schemes, including HTTP Digest. See: https://github.com/ciaranj/express-auth

Another excellent option is `passport` at: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport

The http-digest examples in the two modules tend to focus on establishing an authentication for you node.js application vs. forwarding the authentication request to a third-party. However, you should be able to make it work with a little noodling.

If pressed, i would use passport. The examples offered are a lot more clear and documented.

Hope that helps...

Comment: `express-auth` and `passport` are libraries for the server side, But the question was how to do a client request.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomand you to use mikeal's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module it make it a lot easier and cleaner.

Request does not have support for HTTP Auth yet, saddly but you would just have to set the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 0):

**Try [urllib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urllib) it will work with simple and disgest auth.**

**See Exemple :** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57221051/8490598