# Node JS get key value pairs from header

Tags: javascript, node.js

If the request contains a header such as:

```
Authorization: Digest username="Mufasa",
                      realm="testrealm@host.com",
                      nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093"
```

Does node have any built-in way to extract the key value pairs? Or should I just use `string.split`?

Comment: You can try `querystring.parse` : http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Comment: @TomerArazy: That's not a querystring.

Comment: You can get req.headers["Authorization"] and then parse the digest like the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850646/cant-get-digest-auth-to-work-with-node-js

Comment: Looks like you're on your own @Gerve :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the URL module http://nodejs.org/api/url.html

```
Example: http://www.host.com:8080/path?name=daniel
```

Takes a URL string, and return an object.
url.parse(urlStr, [parseQueryString], [slashesDenoteHost])

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end('Hello ' + queryData.name + '\n');
}
```

In this example name is mapped to daniel.

Comment: The string that I'm parsing isn't a query string, it's a header.

Comment: If you can format your data transmission into JSON, then just use JSON.parse(data);